# Why should you use the <label> tag and 'for' attribute?

Tags: html, forms, seo

You can label an input field with a `<label>` tag like this:

```
<label for="username">Username:</label>
<input id="username" name="username" type="text">
```

But why?

Is it effective for SEO? Or browser rendering? Or better support for mobile or other devices?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `label` tag supports with a click the focus on the `input` element where `id` attribute equals labels `for` attribute. 
If you have e.g. a checkbox you can choose this one also with a click on the label.

Example:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" id="myCheckbox"/>

// A click here set the focus on the according checkbox without javascript things 
// And it's easier to select than a small checkbox element 
<label for="myCheckbox">My Checkbox</label>
```

Comment: please add an example of what you are saying, it would be more clear for OP to understand

Comment: Example here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_label  Otherwise, clear answer

Answer (score 8):

The primary benefits are:

- Accessibility - it lets screen readers know which form control the text applies to, this lets them accurately tell the user what they are expected to enter in a field
- Click targets - clicking on the label has the same effect as clicking on the form control, larger click targets are easier to hit, especially when the input is as small as a radio button

Comment: But for accessibility you can also use `<p>` or `<span>`. So there is not some benefit more why you should use it as the click targets?

Comment: @AndreasFurster — How do you tell a screen reader that a `<p>` or a `<span>` contains text that describes the purpose of a form control (as opposed to being some text between two form controls)? The HTML specification only gives `<label>` that power.

Comment: No, a piece of software that uses speech to describe what is on the screen to someone who is (typically) blind.

Comment: Can you add some code like in the other answer? Then i will accept yours.

Comment: @AndreasFurster — What would be the point of adding code? You have code in the question. You were asking what it does. I explained. Copy/pasting it from the question to the answer would be a waste of space.